# Multiple tax_query with relation OR

Tags: mysql, wordpress, taxonomy

I have an taxonomy that may be have one or more items with selection.  Is possible on WP_Query with tax_query and specify if can get results with relation 'OR' that is possible or select A or B (for example) using the same parametter?

```
if (isset($_GET['area']) && !empty($_GET['area'])) {
   if(is_array($_GET['area'])) {

     foreach($_GET['area'] as $a) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
          'taxonomy' => 'property_area',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => array($a),
        );
     }    
   }
 }
```

Because on this query the final SQL may be:

```
AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (232) AND tt2.term_taxonomy_id IN (250)
```

And if was with relation OR the results is the same.

Because on sample:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'quotes' ),
        ),
        array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( 'post-format-quote' ),
                        ),
                        array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                'field'    => 'slug',
                                'terms'    => array( 'wisdom' ),
                        ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Is possible to make and like "sub tax_query" srictly doing an relation 'OR'?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking, your question is very confusing! Your examples include AND and OR so I'm not sure which you are looking for. Can you explain more simply what you want to do? For example, are you trying to search for posts where `property_area = area1 OR property_area = area2`?